# What is &>> in a shell script

Tags: bash

In a script I have inherited the output of one of our programs is put in to a file with:

```
program &>> result.txt
```

I have been reading in my book "Learning the bash shell" at home over the weekend, but cannot find what this means ( I know what `>`and `>>` mean ).

I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 44):

Your book is likely too old, this is something new in Bash version 4.

```
program &>> result.txt
```

is equivalent to

```
program >> result.txt 2>&1
```

Redirect and append both stdout and stderr to file `result.txt`.
More about I/O redirection [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Comment: Be careful with this syntax, running in anything other than bash (ie /bin/sh) then this backgrounds the process and then redirects to result.txt. Make sure /bin/bash is used

Answer (score 15):

`&` means both standard output (`1>`) and standard error(`2>`).

`>>` means append to end of the file.

You can use `1>>a 2>&1` instead of `&>>`

Eg. `date test >>file 2>&1`